# Hiding sensitive information that is in the response

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a method that needs to return List emails that one user has. I am looking for a solution how to hide the response from this specific method, because the emails of the user are very sensitive information in this case. I tried to add @JsonIgnore( org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore; )to the get method inside User class and to the field also, but that is not the solution in my case. This is the method that i created

```
public List<String> getUsersEmails(String username){
    User user = userDao.getUserByUsername(username);
    if(user != null){
        if(user.getEmails() != null && !user.getEmails().isEmpty()){
            return user.getEmails();
        }
    }

     return null;
}
```

I am looking for a way when i cick on Inspect Element - > open the call -> open response to be empty ( hidden )

Answer (score 0):

Email is sent in text form, and is relayed through dozens of non-recipient servers before it arrives at the recipient server.

If you are sending sensitive information, every recipient can read it, even though the are just intermediate "post offices."

The only correct solution is to encrypt the sensitive parts, before sending the email, with a routine that doesn't have all of the required components to decrypt it in the same email.  This approach also means that either the email client will need to support the decrypting (web browser client or desktop client) within the client code, or the email will have to be saved and then decrypted.

Comment: But that was not my question. I don't want to hide whats in the email. I have a method that returns list of emails example email1@gmail.com,email2@gmail.com and i don't want this to be shown in the response